# alias for 'emacs /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects'

Tags: alias, ln

I'm trying to get the following working:

```
alias banana='emacs /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/'
```

So i want to just type "banana firewall.cfg" to edit this file(/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/firewall.cfg).
If i type that, emacs opens two buffers, one for "/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects" in directory edit mode, and the other just as a blank second file called firewall.cfg, which is expected, and obviously the command "bananafirewall.cfg" doesn't work.

I've been scratching my head for a good 30 minutes.
Is alias even the right command for this?
I guess I could ln -s all these files to /root, but any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are good for giving another name to a command, or for passing default arguments. They are not good beyond that, for example to modify an argument. Use a function instead.

To support multiple file names easily, change to the target directory first. Use parentheses instead of braces to create a subshell so that the directory change does not affect the parent shell.

```
banana () (
  cd /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/ &&
  emacs "$@"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a shell function like this:

```
banana () { emacs /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/"$1"; }
```

Only works with one filename. To support more than one would make it more complicated.

Comment: This is the right answer. From `bash` manpage: There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used.